# Can't call any methods made available by FBO.gov's web API

Tags: python-3.x, zeep

I'm trying to get data from [fbo.gov](https://www.fbo.gov/), which is a government website where they post contracts that vendors can bid in. They have a [document](https://www.fbo.gov/downloads/fbo_web_services_technical_documentation.pdf) containing ways of accessing information on the site through SOAP requests, which is what I'm trying to do. Although all of the examples in that document are in PHP, I am trying to make my requests in Python, because I've never done anything with PHP before.

To make the SOAP requests in Python, I'm using [zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Right now, I can successfully authenticate myself through HTTP, but no matter what method I try to call, I always get the same error: `This user has an inactive agency.`

Here is the code I'm using to send the request

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import zeep
from zeep.transports import Transport

test = "https://fbo-test.symplicity.com"
prod = "https://fbo.gov"

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("sample_username", "sample_password")
client = zeep.Client(f"{test}/ws/fbo_api.php?wsdl", transport=Transport(session=session))

dictionary = {"notice_type": "PRESOL"}
print(client.service.getList(data=dictionary))
```

I realize this is a long shot, but what could be causing this error? I can't find *anything* even remotely related to the error anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I'm attempting the same thing and seeing the same error. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: I'm wondering if the error is due to an account flag on the FBO side. The reason I'm thinking this, is that if I change the username or password to be invalid, or the body of the request to be invalid, then I get different errors.

Comment: I also tried crafting the SOAP request manually and using Python requests.post() and was able to duplicate `This user has an inactive agency.` without zeep in the mix.

Comment: I was never able to resolve it; me and the rest of the team moved on from it to try the new sam.gov

Answer (score 0):

Per the Federal Service Desk:

> The FBO API is only available for government user accounts.

Some of the FBO data is available at: ftp://ftp.fbo.gov

Currently, FBO is in the process of moving to SAM, and will have a public API once the move is complete. The new API is under development, with the latest specification at: https://open.gsa.gov/api/get-opportunities-public-api/

Answer (score 0):

FBO.GOV has been retired as of 11/12/2019 along with the ftp.fbo.gov bulk download, use the following instead,

https://open.gsa.gov/api/sam-entity-extracts-api/